# How can we make Javascript arrays immutable like for Objects we have Object.freeze() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, immutability

For ex:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
arr.push(4);    //4
console.log(arr) //[1,2,3,4]
```

I want this array to be immutable. It should not allow push or add/delete arr values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [`Freeze array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Freezing_arrays)

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
Object.freeze(arr)
arr.push(5);
```

***Note:-*** it will do shallow freeze,

```js
const arr = [1, 2, {key: 123}];
Object.freeze(arr)
arr[2].key = 'changed value'

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Object.freeze` works just fine on arrays, since arrays are objects as well:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
Object.freeze(arr);
arr.push(4);    // attempting to push throws
```

Comment: Yup. This also prevents assignment using the indexer, as you might expect.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays *are* objects - so it'll work fine:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.freeze(arr);
arr.push(4);
arr[arr.length - 1] = 4;
```

The index assignment method also fails:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.freeze(arr);
arr[arr.length - 1] = 4;
```